# Media Queries Not Working in WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, media-queries

First post here:

Writing custom code for a WordPress site. The PHP and CSS working fine (both are custom pages created from scratch but properly "plugged in" to WordPress and rendering fine.) Time to start coding for various sizes via Media Queries. But first, a test -- that I can't make work. I've placed media queries inside all ready-confirmed working stylesheet. Things tried/confirmed are not the problem:

• I have the "viewport" code in the head (WordPress's header.php file)

• My media query is AFTER "default" CSS code (see below)

• Tried min-width along with mid-device-width along with @media only screen and @media screen - neither work (nor do its various combinations)

• Triple checked spelling and syntax errors

• Tried putting space around colon (min-width: 1200px) vs (min-width : 1200px) - nothing

• Pre-existing media queries elsewhere within the site are rendering fine in the browser (ie - the header.php, style.css, etc) - but my code is all custom, using unique selectors so shouldn't conflict - just saying "its not the browser"

• Researched on this site and Google answers but nothing appears to work (I am aware of viewport vs device width issues as stated above) -- These "usual suspects" all seem to be non-issue.

So.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

```css
.formtitle {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: .5%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1599px) {
  .formtitle {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #f24950;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: .5%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="smallform">
  <span class="formtitle">Contact Us Today!</span> [contact-form-7 id="12016" title="DitL Form"]
</div>
```

Comment: I converted your code to snippet and it definitely works. I'd say that elsewhere in your styles you probably have a rule overriding this one.

Comment: Thanks, the selector is unique. (there is no other formtitle class as I "invented it") - meaning, it isn't a duplicate of a WordPress artifact or used elsewhere. I'm fuzzy on how another rule could be overriding this one if it doesn't exist. Elaborate? -- Still, I tried to add more rules to my media query to test your guess (with unique names) as well as plain ole HTML selectors like "body" and "p" and still....nothing) - I also did a "search" for the class formtitle in all other CSS sheets the site uses and can confirm "formtitle" is no where else...Clearing my cache didn't work either. :\

Comment: Is this live somewhere? I could take a look.

Comment: www.ico.edu/a-day-in-the-life

Comment: I don't see the media query anywhere in your css. It just doesn't exist.

Comment: hmmm - why would that be? When i go to Wordpress > Appearance > Editor, and then select the custom css file I made, its there. Not to mention, the media query is at the bottom of the CSS that *is* executing properly. Why would the browser read the "normal" CSS and then get to the media query and stop? (Thanks for sticking with me on this. I am totally out of ideas.)

Comment: Which file is the media query in? I literally don't see it at all. Your `style.css` has no mention of `.formtitle` and `style_ditl.css` has only one mention, the regular style definition.

Comment: ya - the media query is at the bottom of style_ditl.css (which *does* shows in WordPress' native code editor). You're correct, there is no mention of it in style.css (hence I don't think its an override rule as originally suspected) -
 Any idea why it wouldn't show/read in the browser but would in WP editor? Can I add screen shots here?

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins? The file being served definitely does not contain the media query: http://www.ico.edu/wp-content/themes/Mexin_child_theme/style_ditl.css?ver=1.0.1

Comment: I'd also like to note I had a similar problem with getting my unique CSS file (style_ditl.css) to "be read" by the browser. The code showed in WP native editor but not in the browser. Come to find out, I had to add some "enque" PHP code to the functions.php WP file for "multiple CSS files to be read." Do you think it might be some weird fix like that? Cause again, the media query is the very next line after the "normal" CSS in "style_ditl.css" executes -- I've even tried to wrap my "normal" CSS its own media query to make the distinction clear...still, nothing.

Comment: No cache plugins and I've cleared my browsing cache several times...do you know why the file being served doesn't show the media query? Just as in my original post, the MQ is right underneath where the "normal code" stops. I don't get why it's just "stop working" from one line to the next...(esp with media queries in WP's style.css execute fine)

Comment: Sorry man I'm not sure, that's dependent on your configuration. I can't keep guessing. The final point is - there's nothing wrong with your css styles, the problem is with wordpress loading or serving the stylesheet file itself.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway. I'll keep trying

Comment: cosnole shows that the style_ditl.css isn't loading. Are you tryin to load this with <link> in head, or enqueing in functions.php? Try the latter and see if it helps

Comment: I saw that too (as did Serg) -- but the crazy thing: the CSS inside of style_ditl.css IS loading even though the console says "404, no its not" --
 Banging my head against the wall until I discovered the "enqued with functions.php" solution to get WP to "read multiple CSS files" -- so YAY! The style_ditl.css is executing after I modified functions.php -- the rub is the media query is literally the next line of code in style_ditl.css and as you said, the console still "reports" it is not being loaded (but is obviously executing) - strange

Answer (score 2):

I found your question in a search result, and had the same problem.

It seems, Wordpress doesn't like the way Bootstrap is writing it's mediaqueries with the comment sections. See below.

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

Should be:

```
/* Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)*/
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) { ... }

/* Large devices (desktops, 992px and up) */ 
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

I assume you've fixed the problem allready but i think it's helpfull for others who are in search for an answer :-)

Comment: Hey, for me both your code blocks look exactly the same.